# Can we change the text color of a complete activity through a single line in Android XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, tags

I want to change the color of all the text written in an activity whether it's a `Button` or a `TextView`.

So, is there any attribute available in Android for XML which can do so, or can be applied in layout tag?

P.S.: Currently, I am changing the text color individually in all the widgets.

Comment: So,you want to change the activity's background, or all the textViews's color in the respective activity?I don't really understand which one or maybe you mean something else.

Comment: All the TextViews' textcolor in one go.

Comment: I just wanted to ask that is there exist a way for doing this or not.

Comment: And you wish to do it via XML or is it ok if you go for it through java??

Comment: I can go for it through Java too.

Comment: Ok well, than it goes like this.You check all the things you want to check ,if they have their parent (View) is your Layout.You can handle the idea or you want me to give a full answer? :)

Comment: Ok it sounds a bit weird, rushed into an answer and it ended  up bad.So, the thing you have to do is this: Get the TextViews's parent and compare it with the Layout. As long as they are in the Layout you want, you change the color of them.And you can do that with a for or a while.I suppose there is a way to actually specify the Layout and than change the TextView's colors ,but I am not aware of it and I gave you what I used when I was learning android.Again,if you need help with the implementation,I ll help but I have to go at this moment ,so I will be back later on.

Comment: a bit confused. would be helpful if u could give an example for this. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84276/discussion-between-vlad-and-himanshu-aggarwal).

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
     <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
  </style>
```

Then for Buttons:

```
<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Do this with everything you need. (Like EditTexts)

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, you have to add the TextViews programmatically.

Why? Simple, because this way you can have them all inside an array of TextViews.

That means you can iterate through them using a for loop.

Now, that the logics of this are no more in the way, what you have to do is to always check if the parent's TextView is the Layout where you want to change stuff.

So,you do that like this:

```
Layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);

for(i=0;i<=[numberOfTextViews]-1;i++){
   if(tvArray[i].getParent() == Layout){
       tvArray[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
     }
}
```

NOTE! I gave you the logics ,not the exact code you need.You have to integrate the code I gave you here in your application.So please think it yourself too, anyways if I give you the exact lines you need (after you provide your own code...) ,you will use the stuff and than forget everything...